# be + emotional adjectives

Tags: vocabulary

> Be happy! You mustn’t be sad (= don't be sad). (Essential Grammar in Use)

I’m confused whether it’s possible to order other people to have certain emotional accomplishment. Do the two sentences really mean that, or do they just demand the hearer’s outer expression showing pleasure, not showing unhappiness?

Comment: _Be happy_ is not an order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The imperative mood is not only used for commands or requests, but also for [exhortations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exhortation). *Be happy* is an exhortation, not a command.

> Don't worry, be happy.

Comment: Hmm, interesting! I hadn't heard that term before. I wonder; "Hey, cheer up! Smile!" In this case, *smile* is a command, yes? I would also think from context that *cheer up* is a command (perhaps more of a *suggested* command, but it seems to be so nonetheless). So in a similar context, couldn't "be happy" (or "don't be sad") also be a command? "Hey, don't be sad! Give us a smile!" or something similar? (I'm honestly curious; I haven't come across this concept before.) At any rate, very interesting answer. +1!

Comment: "Give us a smile!" could be an exhortation or a command; I would see it more like an exhortation, and consider "smile every time you see me" a command. As for "be happy," I would not see it as a command, since nobody can be commanded to be happy. Then, people would take somebody is happy because something done (e.g. keeping to smile), and somebody could just pretend to be happy.